# What does "occur to an excess" mean?

Tags: grammar

I am getting myself ready for a test and I found this construction which sounds weird to me as I would have used "due to" or "because of", I looked up the meaning of "to" and it doesn't really fit in the next sentence ,"They occur to an excess where epithelium-lined tissue are irritated and inflamed" for saying "the excess" is the cause.
This is the text:
extensions of the epithelium into the connective tissue. They occur to an excess where epithelium-lined tissue are irritated and inflamed such as the junctional epithelium during periodontal disease. Outdated term is rete pegs.

Comment: Occur to an excess = happen too much. (usually _to excess_ - doesn't mean _because of_.)

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries don't just help with individual words; they can help with idioms and phrases, too.

"[To excess](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20excess)" means *more than is usual, normal, or proper*.

Your quotation would appear to suggest that the occurrence perhaps happens occasionally for other reasons, but only happens 'to excess' (too much, more than usual) in the given circumstances.

Comment: I actually found that meaning but it didn't make sense to me.

Comment: I apologize for using this symbol " too much
Could you please tell me which quotation of mine are you referring to?